# Можно ли как то задать круглую тень для шрифтовой иконки?

Tags: css3

Я прописываю:

box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 13px 3px #000000

и получается:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ну так `border-radius` .. задать тень той формы которой у вас png/svg/что-то-там-еще нельзя (css'ом), но если у вас строго круг, то проблем никаких ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
body{
  margin: 0 auto; 
  background: #4CAF50;
}
.container{
  margin-top: 1em;
  text-align: center;
}
/* All Icons*/
.container .fa{
  font-size: 4em;
  padding: 1em;
  color: #fff;
}
.container .fa-linkedin-square{
  text-shadow: 3px 6px #272634;
}
.container .fa-facebook-official{
  text-shadow: 3px 3px 16px #272634;
}
.container .fa-github{
  text-shadow: -7px 8px 2px #c54040, -3px 5px #c74b16;
}
.container .fa-codepen{
  text-shadow: -3px -8px 9px #f78aa0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/fa1e9b250e.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <i class="fa fa-linkedin-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-facebook-official" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-github" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-codepen" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```